# From where does the uboot get the information about flash, RTC, RAM in uboot/kernel development

Tags: c, linux

From where does the uboot get the information about flash, RTC, RAM in uboot/kernel development

Answer (score 3):

If you're looking for board specific things check
 .../include/configs/yourboard.h

Answer (score 1):

That is spread throughout the u-boot source tree. A more specific question would probably get you a better answer.